# Numpy indexing assignement preserve contiguousness?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Let suppose that I have a contiguous array:

```
contiguous_array = np.ascontiguousarray(...)
```

and another non necessarily contiguous array:

```
generic = np.array([10, 100, 1000])
```

if I do something like that:

```
indices = [0, 5, 10]
contiguous_array[indices] = generic
```

is contiguous_array still contiguous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contiguous_array` will still be contiguous. The assignment copies data into `contiguous_array`'s existing buffer; it does not change the memory layout. It is impossible to make a contiguous array non-contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

when you have created a C_contigous array (x), later you created a numpy array and replaced the elements of x by selecting the indeices.
ex: [Code by replicating your question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctntb.jpg)

but these steps will not change the type of array which is C_Contigous array
[Output to determine the type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIV8Z.jpg)

therefore, contiguous_array cannot be changed to non contiguous.